# Looking up how much direct buffer memory is available to Java?

Tags: java, nio

How can one look up how much [direct memory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) is currently allocated (and may be allocated) by Java? As the evaluator of https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4879883 mentions, Java maintains these buffers outside the normal Java heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do this with native code (or profiling, etc.), but something like this might work in Java:

```
Class c = java.nio.Bits.class;
Field maxMemory = c.getDeclaredField("maxMemory");
maxMemory.setAccessible(true);
Field reservedMemory = c.getDeclaredField("reservedMemory");
reservedMemory.setAccessible(true);
synchronized (c) {
    Long maxMemoryValue = (Long)maxMemory.get(null);
    Long reservedMemoryValue = (Long)reservedMemory.get(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I rather did this to get the class instance: `javaNioBitsClass = Class.forName("java.nio.Bits");` because this class is package-protected by default.